# Where are the version 2 of the MTProIILite fonts?

Tags: fonts, mtpro

At the bottom of the first page of the documentation for the "mtp2lite" package at:

```
ctan:/fonts/mtp2lite/texmf/doc/fonts/mtpro2/mtpro2.pdf
```

it is stated that:

```
This document refers to version v2.1a of the mtpro2 package,
to be used with version 2 of the MathTımeProfessional II fonts.
```

Now if one go to the fonts themselves in the package:

```
 ctan:/mtp2lite/texmf/fonts/type1/pctex/mtpro2
```

ALL of them are labelled "Version 1.00".

So where are the free fonts that are supposed to be used with this package?

Comment: http://www.pctex.com/mtpro2.html (seems to be down, [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20170827054007/http://www.pctex.com:80/mtpro2.html) is a snapshot).

Comment: Ah, the download site still works http://www2.pctex.com/downloads.php?product=MTP2L

Comment: @HenriMenke I have been there and downloaded it, and it is not it. The files in there are EAXCTLY the same as the ones in CTAN, and they are all Version1.00.

Comment: Well, I guess it is version 1.00 of MathTime Professional 2 then, because that is the official source.

Comment: @HenriMenke, if the phrase was written by a normal-Joe it could easily be taken as a mistake, but in fact, it is authored by [Walter Schmidt](http://cq131a.de/) of long and known experience with math TeX fonts.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that all outlines are still the same as version 1.0, but some .fd files have changed, so this is where the version 2 comes from:

```
umt2hrb.fd   2009/1/30 v2.2 MathTimePro II Holey Roman Bold (PCTeX/WaS)
umt2ms.fd    2009/1/30 v2.2 MathTimePro II Script (PCTeX/WaS)
umt2hrb.fd   2009/1/30 v2.2 MathTimePro II Holey Roman Bold (PCTeX/WaS)
umt2ms.fd    2009/1/30 v2.2 MathTimePro II Script (PCTeX/WaS)
```